# AFNetworking POST returns 999 error

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

In my app I'm doing a `POST` to an API. In this case I'm setting the base url to `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/`. Then I execute the code below:

```
[self POST:@"posts"
    parameters:nil
    constructingBodyWithBlock:nil
    success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"response: %@", responseObject);
        success(responseObject);
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        failure(error);
    }];
```

When this code is run, an error is logged.

```
Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts}
```

I tried changing the security policy.

```
AFSecurityPolicy *securityPolicy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeNone];
securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;
[securityPolicy setValidatesDomainName:NO];

self.securityPolicy = securityPolicy;
```

I also tried changing the transport security. Both of these solutions did nothing. Any ideas as to what could be going wrong?

Comment: Found a solution?

Answer (score -2):

Add this in your `info.plist`:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>example.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xNAC.png

Comment: Per the original question: "I also tried changing the transport security. Both of these solutions did nothing.".